# Оптимизация скрипта обработки больших объемов данных

Tags: php, mysql

Господа программисты, требуется профессиональный совет или идея по увеличению скорости скрипта на php.
Что скрипт делает:

1.Загружает, обрабатывает и csv-файл с данными, записывая это дело в базу MySQL

2.Потом пользователь вводит некие данные (в данном случае-стоимость единицы услуги от каждого из известных провайдеров)

3.Скрипт выгружает из базы массив данных, обрабатывает каждую запись с помощью mysql _ fetch _ array, по префиксу определяя провайдера и подставляя нужную стоимость+вычисляя итоговую стоимость (количество ед. услуг * стоимость) сейчас с помощью оператора if, так как на практике он оказался быстрее switch-case. И построчно записывает это в *.xls файл.

Как можно оптимизировать/ускорить этот скрипт? Потому как при обработке 40.000 записей возвращает сообщение о превышении тайм-аута. да и 15.000 записей обрабатывает ~5 мин.

Идеи есть?

Comment: Вы пробовали использовать PDO?
http://habrahabr.ru/post/137664/

Answer (score 1):

Трудно судить не видя реализации. Но из того что нужно перво-наперво проверить
1) если это InnoDB таблица - вставлять данные кусками используя транзакции, если MyISAM - то формировать группу запросов и сразу добавлять
2) Проверить правильность простановки индексов на БД
3) Найти узкое место среди 3х этапов. Может у Вас все хорошо и самое долгое, скажем 99%, это загрузка CSV.

а так, это гадание на кофейной гуще. Сделайте замеры скорости каждого из этапов и смотрите где тормоза идут. Выборка из 40.000 - при правильных индексов - доли секунды. Насколько сложные данные загружаются и как они выгружаются - тесты, тесты, тесты.

кстати, из всего описанного мне не нравится больше всего именно 3ий пункт. То что вы все парсите. Может правильнее на стадии загрузки правильно распарсить и разнести данные так, чтобы потом  просто выбирать нужное, а не на PHP все это дело формировать.

Comment: У меня по итогу получилось, что самая проблема- не в загрузке csv. CSV грузится моментально, а вот с обработкой проблемы. Тесты показывают, что сама проблема в количестве обрабатываемых данных. То есть, проблема начинается в момент обработки строк и записи в *.xls файл. Но проблемы с записью в xls тоже нету. Остается- только обработка данных построчно.

Comment: А вот с разносом данных - идея хорошая, надо подумать и попробовать.

Comment: ну в этом случае, при добавлении данных сразу разбивайте по префиксам и когда делаете выборку, сразу выбирайте те данные, префикс которых нужен.